# NHibernate won't connect to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have 3 SQL Server instances running on our server (dont ask why)!

2xSQL Server 2008 Workgroup (Default and MSSQLServer2)
1xSQL Server Express 2008 R2 (sqlexpress)

Now I have a Windows Service/App that runs a process in the background. The databases are pretty much the same, however whenever I try and run the service on the MSSQLServer2 instance NHibernate throws an exception.

I have checked my connections strings and it seems fine, as I've been able to copy the others, to be sure.

I've reset the account password I am using and checked that I can connected to it using Management Studio with the new creds.

I dont know what else to test. The app loads (as it creates a Log4View entry) but as soon as it makes its first NHibernate request it crashes, with a the following dump and no additional event log:

> Description:   Stopped working
>
> Problem signature:   Problem Event
>   Name: CLR20r3   Problem Signature
>   01:   R2K3ITVW3VUVRUM1CITUNG1NSZBMATAX
>   Problem Signature 02: 1.0.0.0
>   Problem Signature 03: 4de87428
>   Problem Signature 04: NHibernate
>   Problem Signature 05: 1.2.0.4000
>   Problem Signature 06: 4639a07f
>   Problem Signature 07: 2ad   Problem
>   Signature 08: 78   Problem Signature
>   09:   NHibernate.LazyInitialization   OS
>   Version:  6.0.6001.2.1.0.272.7   Locale
>   ID:   2057
>
> Read our privacy statement:
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=50163&clcid=0x0409

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned, the log event does not give much information.

LazyInitialization exceptions are thrown if objects are not fully instantiated. Usually, I would expect an error message like *cannot connect to the database*. Hence, I expect some flaws in the code. At least, I assume that it is not properly checked whether a connection to the database was established successfully before doing other hibernate stuff like instantiating objects.

After talking about some more code-centric stuff, let's consider the cause and possible workarounds. My eye caught one difference: you encounter exceptions only when connecting the the non-default instance. I guess, this one is not on the standard port (1433).

Maybe the port number is hard coded (1433)? It looks as if the applications works only with default instances. You could try to manually configure your instance *MSSQLServer2* to use port 1433, just for troubleshooting. Are there config files or registry entries where to specify the port number? Or is the port number given in the connection string? Should the application be really hard coded to use the default instance and / or port 1433, there is in my opinion nothing that you can do as an administrator to make it working with the second instance.